# Importing cx_Oracle causes an Apache server to throw an internal server error

Tags: python, linux, oracle, apache, cx-oracle

I'm trying to configure the `cx_Oracle` python module to work with an Apache server on RHL.

I installed the python module and the oracle client on my user account and after some configuration it worked fine (I had to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable and create a sym link to `libclntsh.so.12.1`).

Now I wanted to use this module with an Apache server, but after importing it in one of my python scripts the server started throwing a 500 error. The only things I changed in the configuration was setting `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `$ORACLE_HOME` as global variables just to be sure and setting the `$PYTHON_EGG_CACHE` to `/tmp` so there aren't any permission issues.

After that the server was still not working so I wanted to see what the error is. I run these commands:

```
sudo su
sudo -u apache python
>>> import cx_Oracle
```

This worked fine and now I'm really confused about why it's not working on the server. Is there something I'm misunderstanding or doing wrong?

EDIT: Just to clarify, the Apache server is on the same machine as my user account.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the library search path environment variables is often the weak point.  How and where you set them depends on your Apache version.  In particular sometimes you use shell syntax (and referenced variables get expanded), other times you need absolute paths.

If you have installed Oracle Instant Client (and have no other Oracle software) then just use `ldconfig` as described in the [Instant Client installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst) (and don't set LD_LIBRARY_PATH or ORACLE_HOME).

Otherwise or RHL you probably want to edit `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` and add something like:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/cjones/instantclient
```

or

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/cjones/instantclient
```

But your boot scripts may be different, so check what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will check this as soon as I can. One thing I still don't understand is how can this work when I'm running it manually as apache user and not work when it's run on the server. Shouldn't the env variables be the same in both cases?

Comment: The resetting/removing of environment variables before system programs start, or when su'ing could be considered a security feature.